# Como definir uma imagem, vinda do banco de dados e que está armazenada em binário, como background-image de uma div?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho uma imagem que é armazenada no banco de dados de **forma binária**. Eu resgatei essa imagem (através de um **select**) e gostaria de inseri-la como background-image de uma **div**. Eu só consigo inseri-la como **src** de uma **img**.

**Como Armazeno no banco de dados**

```html
$foto = $_FILES['foto']['name'];

if($this->__get('foto') != "")
{
  $binario = file_get_contents($this->__get('foto')); 
  $query = "UPDATE usuarios SET foto = :foto, nome = :nome, usuario = :usuario, telefone = :telefone, email = :email, email_alternativo = :email_alternativo, frase = :frase, senha = :senha, lembrete = :lembrete, biografia = :biografia ";
  $query .= "WHERE id = :id";
    
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindValue(':foto', $binario);
  $stmt->bindValue(':nome', $this->__get('nome'));
  $stmt->bindValue(':usuario', $this->__get('usuario'));
  $stmt->bindValue(':telefone', $this->__get('telefone'));
  $stmt->bindValue(':email', $this->__get('email'));
  $stmt->bindValue(':email_alternativo', $this->__get('email_alternativo'));
  $stmt->bindValue(':frase', $this->__get('frase'));
  $stmt->bindValue(':senha', $this->__get('senha'));
  $stmt->bindValue(':lembrete', $this->__get('lembrete'));
  $stmt->bindValue(':biografia', $this->__get('biografia'));
  $stmt->bindValue(':id', $this->__get('id'));
  $stmt->execute();  
}
```

**Parte que eu insiro como src de um img**.

```html
<?php
      
function dataURI($bin)
{
  return 'data: image/gif;base64,'.base64_encode( $bin );
}    
     
?>


  <div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center" id="div-foto-usuario">
      <?php        
  if(!empty($this->view->info_usuario['foto']))
  {          

   $foto = dataURI($this->view->info_usuario['foto']);
   
   echo "<img id='img-imagem-usuario' class='mr-2 border border-secondary' src='$foto' style='border-radius:50%;width:120px; height:120px;'>";    
  }
  else
  {
   echo "<img id='img-imagem-usuario' class='mr-2 border border-secondary' src='/img/usuario.jpg' style='border-radius:50%;width:120px; height:120px;'>";
  }
 ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Eu gostaria de inserir no background-image da div abaixo:**

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $foto; ?>);">
  </div>
</div>
```

- Tentei, no desespero, dar um echo da variável que contém a imagem dentro do url(), porém não deu certo.
- Código HTML gerado da página: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6d0jyaup/)

Comment: Como ficou longa, a conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101659/discussion-on-question-by-thiaguinho-embasamento-como-definir-uma-imagem-vinda) e pode prosseguir clicando no link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se fosse uma URL normal, o valor de `url` no `background-image` não necessitaria ser delimitado por aspas, mas no caso de base64, é preciso.

Como os valores da `style` da div estão delimitados por aspas duplas, basta você delimitar o valor da `url` com aspas simples:

```
background-image: url('<?php echo $foto; ?>');
```

Comment: Mas, @Sam. Essa parte do código está funcionando. O img está recebendo a imagem da variável de boa. O problema é a div que não recebe o background image.

Comment: Ah eh... vc quer inserir como background a `$foto`?

Comment: Acho que entendi agora, é outra div. Cara, é só colocar dentro de aspas simples: `background-image: url('código binário aqui');`

Comment: O style está com aspas duplas, certo? então vc coloca o valor da `url` em aspas simples.

Comment: Exatamente, isso. @Sam. O carinha também acabou de me falar isso em um grupo no telegram.

Comment: Edita a resposta ai. Pra eu aceitar.

Comment: Muito obrigado, @Sam. Vc sempre nos salvando.

Comment: Resposta alterada. Valeu!!